# Electrum's custom Base43 - looking for a 2-way deterministic hex converter

Tags: transactions, electrum, qrcode, encoding, tools

I am looking for a tool, suitable for an amnesiac offline air-gapped Linux Live host

that will deterministically convert in both directions, between raw hex and Electrum's custom Base43 format, used to fit 2900+ bytes of BTC transaction data into L-40 QR codes,

without my needing to learn to program, please!

...
functions from Electrum:

base_encode(tx_bytes, base=43)

base_decode(raw, base=43).hex()

...
This tool only decodes, no encoding

http://electrum43.org

https://github.com/jacoblyles/base43js

...
references:

https://jacobexmachina.blogspot.com/2016/10/using-electrum-on-airgapped-machine.html

https://www.mail-archive.com/bitcoin-development@lists.sourceforge.net/msg04330.html

https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2015-February/007613.html

https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/issues/5746

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed like an interesting thing to do. So I created a tool to do it.

https://github.com/redgrittybrick/base43

```
C> type example.base43.txt
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

C> base43 -decode -hex < example.base43.txt
0100000001ac01d39c405d31d3d20b00254e84dce9838b9c280f3aa07bf77a1510d8f8779900000000fd4201004830450221009a4065d3b869f20b6e858e0722d9b511213e09dcf1b61072cccbff340c7f424e022034c42927a64fe323d8e8b76d99960322bf0664fdad9994939aedac74a32ca8c701483045022100dda3d5974ae1c06d9742c7aa5e2f789218054c60476f049300c7d4d0395819aa02201f484d7a2b4cc6186b23f54ea4099a728760d71fcc0c7a82bd056c6eaeacf3ab014cad5221020de4d18c5b852a3c1d1f1033a812b019c396b75cab2a248089b09632c7bbdda221024ee8ab3639ea02d7fac7e90078b16c06811573d7046cd06b5d1d8d7e50e0767a21025392159aaf967c2f7e1dca92b68d1b3abaf44a9d3903f7382e76f9f64e7bfa242102df269b98c7ea5bdec1aac268d6107b827163d3a0ca8bd3522279d14c46e1bf1a2103cfbf85d74dddf892b3b6f918fd36dab13cc904d9ba3c9306e9e25fe53ebde08155aeffffffff01131f0000000000001976a914e9cc1b59c97f860f5c629c23d93920da60648d0388ac00000000

C> type example.hex.txt
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

C> base43 -hex < example.hex.txt
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
```

Seems OK.

The code is simple enough to be read and seen to be free of any malicious intent by almost anyone. I would suggest that any program used in connection with cryptocurrency should be compiled from source after inspecting the code. The go compiler is a free download from golang.org. Use `go build` to create a program from the source code.

Comment: Wow. Dunno what to say? So cool. and thank you, so honored

Answer (score 0):

Another kind soul from Reddit:

There were some bugs in jacoblyles/base43js

I fixed them and made a simple html file with all the needed JS embedded.

https://pastebin.com/WHk7iryz

Save it to an html file and open it in a browser.

...

https://www.reddit.com/r/Electrum/comments/ts03xj/electrums_custom_base43_looking_for_a_2way